# Numpy/Numba performance issues when processing conditions and masking logical_and

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization, numba

I want to compute many rows of dataframe and check if a condition is then satisfied in every row for every column. I implemented a straigthforward solution using for loop and compiled it using numba (test1), which run very fast, but I tought vectorizing it will bring me even faster results.

I then tried logical ands of all my conditioned arrays (test2), which is slightly faster, but I need even more faster solution, preferably < 1ms for million of columns and 20 rows.
As the condition in this example to be passed (all True in all rows) is with probablity of 1/32 and it will be even lower for real data, it doesn't make sense to compute all the conditions (greater or less then 0) for every row, as False value in any row can be automatically evaluated as False.

So I wanted to use a masked array (test3), where I iteratively compute the True/False values for the first row and then mask only the True values in other rows, saving the needs to compute the full length of array, and the speed should even decrease with more rows, as there will be less and less masked values for last rows.

Ironically the solution I tought would be the fastest is 10x slower then non-masked version. What is the issue here? Is it that masking and re-assigning True/False values is performing slower than just computing all condiditions?

Is there any way how to further speed this code?
Thanks

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def test1(df_np):
    truth_arr = np.full(df_np.shape[0], False)
    for i in range(df_np.shape[0]):
        truth_arr[i] = df_np[i, 5] > 0 and df_np[i, 6] > 0 and df_np[i, 7] > 0 and df_np[i, 8] > 0 and df_np[i, 9] > 0    

@njit
def test2(df_np):
    return True & \
        (df_np[:, 5] > 0) & \
        (df_np[:, 6] > 0) & \
        (df_np[:, 7] > 0) & \
        (df_np[:, 8] > 0) & \
        (df_np[:, 9] > 0)

@njit
def test3(df_np):
    truth_arr = np.full(df_np.shape[0], True)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 5][truth_arr] > 0)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 6][truth_arr] > 0)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 7][truth_arr] > 0)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 8][truth_arr] > 0)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 9][truth_arr] > 0)
```

The benchmarks are:

```py
df_np = np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(1_000_000, 10))

%%timeit
test1(df_np)
# 8.71 ms ± 93.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
test2(df_np)
# 4.6 ms ± 97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
test3(df_np)
# 47.7 ms ± 825 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: `test3()` is making a lot of extra work the other approaches will not do. `test1()` could be made faster if replacing `np.full()` with `np.empty()` and possibly `range()` with `numba.prange()` (and `njit(parallel=True)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craft a number of additional tests:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def test1(df_np):
    truth_arr = np.full(df_np.shape[0], False)
    for i in range(df_np.shape[0]):
        truth_arr[i] = df_np[i, 5] > 0 and df_np[i, 6] > 0 and df_np[i, 7] > 0 and df_np[i, 8] > 0 and df_np[i, 9] > 0    
    return truth_arr


@nb.njit
def test2(df_np):
    return \
        (df_np[:, 5] > 0) & \
        (df_np[:, 6] > 0) & \
        (df_np[:, 7] > 0) & \
        (df_np[:, 8] > 0) & \
        (df_np[:, 9] > 0)


@nb.njit
def test3(df_np):
    truth_arr = np.full(df_np.shape[0], True)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 5][truth_arr] > 0)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 6][truth_arr] > 0)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 7][truth_arr] > 0)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 8][truth_arr] > 0)
    truth_arr[truth_arr] &= (df_np[:, 9][truth_arr] > 0)
    return truth_arr


@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def test4(df_np):
    n, m = df_np.shape
    truth_arr = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        truth_arr[i] = df_np[i, 5] > 0 and df_np[i, 6] > 0 and df_np[i, 7] > 0 and df_np[i, 8] > 0 and df_np[i, 9] > 0
    return truth_arr


@nb.njit
def test5(df_np):
    n, m = df_np.shape
    truth_arr = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in range(n):
        truth_arr[i] = df_np[i, 5] > 0
        for j in range(6, 10):
            if truth_arr[i]:
                truth_arr[i] &= df_np[i, j] > 0
            else:
                break
    return truth_arr


@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def test6(df_np):
    n, m = df_np.shape
    truth_arr = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        truth_arr[i] = df_np[i, 5] > 0
        for j in range(6, 10):
            if truth_arr[i]:
                truth_arr[i] &= df_np[i, j] > 0
            else:
                break
    return truth_arr


@nb.njit
def test7(df_np):
    n, m = df_np.shape
    truth_arr = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in range(n):
        truth_arr[i] = df_np[i, 5] > 0 and df_np[i, 6] > 0 and df_np[i, 7] > 0 and df_np[i, 8] > 0 and df_np[i, 9] > 0
    return truth_arr


@nb.njit
def test8(df_np):
    truth_arr = df_np[:, 5] > 0
    for j in range(6, 10):
        truth_arr &= (df_np[:, 6] > 0)
    return truth_arr


def test9(df_np):
    truth_arr = df_np[:, 5] > 0
    for j in range(6, 10):
        truth_arr &= (df_np[:, 6] > 0)
    return truth_arr
```

Which one will come out faster will depend on your environment.
I recommend trying them out yourself.

Timings on a Google Colab notebook look like:

```py
for func in funcs:
    func(df_np)  # trigger compilation
    print(f"{func.__name__}  ", end="")
    %timeit -n 4 -r 4 func(df_np)
# test1  13.4 ms ± 711 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
# test2  8.39 ms ± 328 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
# test3  63.9 ms ± 585 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
# test4  9.38 ms ± 241 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
# test5  14.1 ms ± 245 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
# test6  8.81 ms ± 453 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
# test7  13.2 ms ± 274 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
# test8  33.8 ms ± 546 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
# test9  34.9 ms ± 340 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
```

`test2()` comes out as slightly faster than `test6()` and `test4()`.

---

Note that there was an issue with earlier implementation not returning the output, thus causing Numba to "optimize" everything away (dead-code elimination).

Comment: Your `test5(df_np)` and `test6(df_np)`  function is missing the initialization `truth_arr[i]=True` before the inner loop. It may also make sense to use `return truth_arr` in all functions, otherwise Numba may optimize away the whole function (dead code elimination).

Comment: @max9111 yep, I borrowed too much from OP :-) Also it is probably better to initialize `truth_arr[i]` with `df_np[i, 5] > 0`.

Comment: thank you for further suggestions, I was not using parallel range, because this function itself is run for multiple conditions across multiple threads using pathos, so using prange will not make this faster. So i think this is the fastest result I can get, maybe only faster solution would be to use a C extension directly.